# How do you skip Chrome's timer before switching to another browser

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome, registry

I must redirect a certain URL from Chrome to Internet Explorer. We are achieving this by changin our registry to send this specific URL on Internet Explorer. We then call `window.open(url)` inside our Angular app.

However, Chrome is delaying the redirection by 3 seconds, with the following message (translated from French):

```
Opening in Internet Explorer in 3 seconds
Your system administrator set up Google Chrome so that Internet Exporer opens to access <url>
```

I noticed that Chrome uses an internal mechanism to perform the redirect, as the URL shown in Chrome during the redirection indicates:

```
chrome://browser-switch/?url=<actual_url>
```

Why is there a 3 second delay, and is there a way to cancel that (using Typescript, preferably) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is a part of ["legacy browser support"](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/chrome/browser/browser_switcher/README.md).

The administrator can set this delay, as documented on [chromeenterprise.google](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#BrowserSwitcherDelay) and the [helpdesk page](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9269998?hl=en&ref_topic=9270153#zippy=%2Cfull-set-of-policies-and-descriptions):

> #### BrowserSwitcherDelay
>
> Specifies the length of time, in milliseconds, that it takes to open the alternative browser. During this time, users see an interstitial page that lets them know they're switching to another browser. If there are issues, users see an error message on the page.
>
> **Unset:** The URL immediately opens in the alternative browser without showing the interstitial page.

The delay is optional, but is only settable through the system administrator policy; it cannot be overridden or controlled through Javascript, or it would defeat the purpose of ensuring the user is aware of what is happening in their browser and why a different browser is opening.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thank you very much ! TIL "legacy browser support"